# dynamic imports in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, code-splitting

I am using server-side rendered vue for my application (not bootstrapped using vue-cli). And my application currently registers all the vue components globally using Vue.component() in the index.js file which is loaded in the base.html of my server.

I need to perform code-splitting, in order to load only the required components as per the url path and to do that I am using the dynamic import syntax for loading the components.

```
Vue.component('component-a', () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "component-a" */ './component-a.vue'))
```

I get the error below (currently loading the components on `http://localhost:8000/dashboard/`)
it tries to search for the chunk in `/dashboard/<chunk.js>` like this :

`GET http://localhost:8000/dashboard/component-a.tmp2hr7_bhp.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

and this

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: () => __webpack_require__.e(/*! import() | component-a */ "component-a").then(__webpack_require__.bind(null, /*! ./component-a.vue */ "./dashboard/static/dashboard/scripts/component-a"))
Reason: ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk component-a failed.
(error: http://localhost:8000/dashboard/component-a.tmp2hr7_bhp.js)
```

I tested this using a basic vue-cli bootstapped app without any custom webpack config, it worked just fine. not sure why this causes a problem here also tried the babel `plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` but didn't work.

Not sure, is there a path problem (as it appends the file chuck name to the url path), since, webpack is not able to find the chunk js file ... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think its a path problem.

Try setting alias in your webpack config (this is what vue-cli uses by default):

```
 alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'yourRootFolder')
    }
```

now use @ in the component path like this.
Vue.component('component-a', () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "component-a" */
'@/component-a.vue'))

Answer (score 0):

This is correct assuming the component is in the same directory:

```
Vue.component('component-a', () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "component-a" */ './component-a.vue'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The filename in your webpack.config.js's *output* property's file name is created dynamically which will have  *[name].[chunkhash].js* you can change it to *[name].js* as mentioned below.

```
output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  ...
},
```

I think this will solve the issue.