# Using conditional require() statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, code-splitting

I am trying to conditionally `require()` modules which are vue components, code snippet below to understand better

`index.js`

So, I want to load different components based on window url (cannot use vue-router as routes are handled using django)

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const pathName = window.location.pathname
let components = []

if(pathName === '/page1/') {
  components = require('./entry-point/page1.entry.js') 
}
else if(pathName === '/page2/') {
  components = require('./entry-point/page2.entry.js')
}

components.forEach(({ name, component }) => {
  Vue.component(name, component)
})
```

`page1.entry.js`

```
const ComponentA = require('../component-a.vue').default
const ComponentB = require('../component-b.vue').default

module.exports = [
    { name: 'component-a', component: ComponentA },
    { name: 'component-b', component: ComponentB }
]
```

`page2.entry.js`

```
const ComponentC = require('../component-c.vue').default

module.exports = [
    { name: 'component-c', component: ComponentC }
]
```

Basically, I am trying split my code and load only the required modules each time `index.js` is loaded. This app is not a typical SSR (Server side rendered) and so using dynamic imports using `import()` is causing problems.

The above code works just fine, only one issue here is, it really `code-splitting` or webpack load all the modules i.e `./entry-point/page1.entry.js` and `./entry-point/page2.entry.js` ?

**So, my question really is, not conditionally requiring modules in the way above really work as desired? or webpack requires all the modules intially?**

Comment: "so using dynamic imports using import() is causing problems" why? How?

Comment: I had already tried dynamic imports - question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769977/dynamic-imports-in-vuejs/62770497#62770497

Answer (score 0):

Using require will not make webpack split your code, you will end up with one giant bundle. only dynamic import will have code splitting.

Also you can load your components in the component that needs it, you are better if you dont register them globally.